# How to loop through dynamic rows while creating DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have the below AMPScript code which is taking input from client side and creates a new DE.

The issue I am facing is I am creating dynamic rows for creating no of fields and its field type -

[image]

How to write in AMPScript to get all the fields and field type.

Below is my AMPScript code:

```
%%[

Set @fname1 = RequestParameter("fname")
Set @sname1 = RequestParameter("sname")
Set @dname1 = RequestParameter("dname")

/*CREATE THE DATA EXTENSION*/
Set @de = CreateObject("DataExtension")
SetObjectProperty(@de,"Name",@dname1)
SetObjectProperty(@de,"CustomerKey",@dname1)
SetObjectProperty(@de,"Description",@dname1)
SetObjectProperty(@de,"IsSendable","True")
SetObjectProperty(@de,"IsTestable","False")

/*DE Folder ID - mouse over in app to get this ID 
SetObjectProperty(@de,"CategoryID","123")*/

/* THIS IS THE SENDABLE FIELD */
Set @deFields = CreateObject("DataExtensionField")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"FieldType",@sname1)
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"IsRequired","true")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"IsPrimaryKey","true")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"IsNillable","false")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"MaxLength","100")
SetObjectProperty(@deFields,"Name",@fname1)
AddObjectArrayItem(@de,"Fields",@deFields)
SetObjectProperty(@de,"SendableDataExtensionField",@deFields)

 /* This field sets how the data extension field above relates to the all subscribers list */
SET @ts_attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Name", "Subscriber Key")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_attr, "Value", "Subscriber Key")
SetObjectProperty(@de,"SendableSubscriberField",@ts_attr)

Set @StatCode = InvokeCreate(@de, @StatMessage, @ErrorCode) 

]%%
Status = %%= v(@StatMessage) =%% -- %%= v(@ErrorCode) =%%
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not readily apparent from the documentation, the AMPScript API functions follow the normal SOAP API structure.

Valid [**DataExtension DataTypes**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextension/) are:

- Text
- Number
- Date
- Boolean
- EmailAddress
- Phone
- Decimal (you also need to set Precision and Scale attributes)
- Locale

Reference:

- [**SOAP API Objects**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/)
- [**DataExtension Object**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextension/)
- [**Creating a Data Extension**](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/data-extensions/data-extension-create.html)
- [**Creating a Data Extension using Web Service API**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_data_extension_using_web_service_api/)